# How to effectively resolve embedded _link objects from REST service with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a REST service that returns object like this:

```
{
  "entityVersion" : 0,
  "creationDate" : "2015-05-24T14:32:08.000+0000",
  "modificationDate" : "2015-05-24T14:32:08.000+0000",
  "creator" : "DUMMY",
  "modifier" : "DUMMY",
  "number" : "Z001/01/2014",
  "issueDate" : "2015-05-24T14:32:08.000+0000",
  "expirationDate" : "2016-05-24T14:32:08.000+0000",
  "status" : "ACTIVE",
  "new" : false,
  "id" : 1,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1"
    },
    "busLineDefinitions" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1/busLineDefinitions"
    },
    "carrier" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1/carrier"
    },
    "schedules" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1/schedules"
    },
    "permitIssuer" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1/permitIssuer"
    },
    "vehicles" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8182/api/domain/permits/1/vehicles"
    }
  }
}
```

Using Restangular, how can I get the object 'permitIssuer' resolved with Restangular? The relation here is one to one (only one permit issuer).

I tried method:

```
$scope.getPermitIssuer = function(permitId) {
   var permitIssuerName;
   Restangular.one("permits", permitId).one('permitIssuer').get().then(function(permIssuer){
        permitIssuerName = permIssuer.name;
   });
   return permitIssuerName;
}
```

but it returns errors:

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Can anyone maybe tell me how to best use Restangular to resolve such embedded dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a way to do that:

```
getPermitIssuer = function(permitId) {
   Restangular.one("permits", permitId).one('permitIssuer').get().then(function(permIssuer){
        $scope.permitIssuerName = permIssuer.name;
   });
}
```